# sqlite3: No such file or directory

Tags: sqlite, android-sdk-tools

I downloaded the ADT Bundle and now cannot run `sqlite` from the `tools` directory.

```
red-planet@desktop:~/Adt-bundle/sdk/tools$ ls 
adb_has_moved.txt  ddms            emulator64-mips  etc1tool         lint          proguard           templates
android            dmtracedump     emulator64-x86   hierarchyviewer  mksdcard      source.properties  traceview
ant                draw9patch      emulator-arm     hprof-conv       monitor       sqlite3            uiautomatorviewer
apkbuilder         emulator        emulator-mips    jobb             monkeyrunner  support            zipalign
apps               emulator64-arm  emulator-x86     lib              NOTICE.txt    systrace
red-planet@desktop:~/Adt-bundle/sdk/tools$ sqlite3 
bash: /home/red-planet/Adt-bundle/sdk/tools/sqlite3: No such file or directory
red-planet@desktop:~/Adt-bundle/sdk/tools$
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The solution.**

I found the solution. I am working on 64-bit Ubuntu and had to make 64-bit applications work on the 64-bit operating system.

`sudo apt-get install ia32-libs`
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/32bit_and_64bit

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04 this worked: `sudo apt-get install lib32z1`

Answer (score -1):

add `./`  before executable files in linux.
try this

```
./sqlite3
```

Comment: It's taken no effect. `red-planet@desktop:~/Adt-bundle/sdk/tools$ ./sqlite3 
bash: ./sqlite3: No such file or directory
red-planet@desktop:~/Adt-bundle/sdk/tools$ `